# How to pass a variable from Rails to Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am trying to implement a progress bar (Javascript) with Ruby on Rails application, but I am having trouble passing values from controller to JS to update the bar.

Initially, I tried using a simple global variable (**$count**) but once loaded, the variable is always the same. It's not updated in the side of JS.

**EDIT:**

Now I am using gon gem to pass the value. But I only get the first value (that was setted when controller starts). When I call a method triggered by a button click, the value is updated but gon variable is always the same. Maybe is an error in rails/controller?

I saw an example with a method to expose variable to gon but is not working.

Note: If I remove the initialization before the search if, when search is clicked JS side shows "gon variable undefined"

Example Code:
application_controller.rb

```
def application 
  @count =0 #gon assumes only this value
  exposeUnProcessedJobToJavascript

  if params[:search]

    while(@count < 10)
      exposeUnProcessedJobToJavascript
      sleep 3
      @count +=1
    end
  end
  def exposeUnProcessedJobToJavascript
    gon.watch.job = @count
  end
end
```

application.js.erb

```
function addJobWatchers() {

  if (gon.job != undefined) {

    gon.watch('job', {
        interval: 1000
    }, updateProcessingJob);
  }
}

function updateProcessingJob(job) {

  if (job) {
    console.log("JOB: " + job);
  }
}

$(document).on('page:change', function() {
 $("#search_button").click(function() {
    console.log("click search");
    if (typeof gon !== 'undefined') {
        addJobWatchers();
    }
 });});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be related with the class. When Ajax try to access method inside class controller, it is instantiated again cleaning all variables.
I solved the problem using **Rails.cache.write(:count,0)** and **Rails.cache.read(:count)** to render the value.
Tip: Doesnt work for multiusers. Rails cache is shared between sessions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a gem that can help you do just that. It has plenty of explanation and examples to get you started.

https://github.com/gazay/gon

Comment: I have already tried gon  gem but it didn t work too. Give an error  when trying to access  variable in js side ":undefined ". Do you know the error?

Comment: How do you set the gon variable in the backend and how do you call it on the js side?

Comment: In the controler i set it gon.var=50  and in js file i try to get  gon.var . Only this. With the gon require in the head of the HTML file.

Comment: I am using gon and now I can get the first value (when controller starts). I just cannot update the value inside a specific method when a search button click. I think the problem is with the methods. Please take a look in the new code if you can find the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this link will do what you are looking for. You shouldn't need the Gon gem. You should only need to do '<%= var %>'

http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript?view=asciicast

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  window.productsURL = '<%= j products_url %>';
  window.products = <%= raw Product.limit(10).to_json %>
<% end %>
```

**Not Best Practice Way:**

Since you already have the @count globally in your template. Set it to a data attribute. Then in your javascript, grab that data attribute. But this is an anti-pattern.

Comment: As I mentioned in the post changes, maybe its a problem with controller. I only can get the value of the variable when controller starts. when I call a search, the variable is not beeing updated.
Please take a look in the new code if you can find the problem. Thanks.